# Doubt regarding Gibbs energy and Electrode potential

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

I have a doubt regarding the relation between Gibbs energy change and E cell, especially when calculating for redox reactions.
This is a question I have seen on a website called "ExamSide questions JEE 2024 Chemistry"

> $$\ce{MnO4^-(aq) + H^+(aq) + C2O4^2-(aq)<=>Mn^2+(aq) + H2O(l) + CO2(g)}$$
> The standard potentials are:
> $E^\circ(MnO_4^-/Mn^{2+}) = +1.51V$
> $E^\circ(CO_2/C_2O_4^{2-}) = -0.49V$
> Find the $K$ for the given redox reaction.

Now, to calculate the net E cell for this reaction, the answer they have provided is:

> $$
> E^\circ_{cell} = E^\circ_{OP,anode} + E^\circ_{RP,cathode}
> = 0.49 + 1.51 = 2V
> $$

Now, if we do the same question using Gibbs energy formula, that is calculating Gibbs energy for each half reaction and adding them up, it goes something like this:

> $$
> \ce{MnO4^- + 8H^+ + 5e^- -> Mn^2+ + 4H2O}$$
> $$\ce{C2O4^2- -> 2CO2 + 2e^-}
> $$
> Balancing and calculating the net Gibbs energy from each of them gives:
> $$\ce{2MnO4^- + 16H^+ + 5C2O4^2- -> 2Mn^2+ + 10CO2 + 8H2O}$$
> $$\Delta_\mathrm{r} G^⦵ = \Delta_\mathrm{r} G^⦵(Oxidation) + \Delta_\mathrm{r} G^⦵(Reduction)$$
> $$
> -n_{net}FE^\circ_{net} = -nFE^\circ_{Oxidation} + -nFE^\circ_{Reduction}
> $$
> $$
> n_{oxidation} = 2, n_{reduction} = 5, and, n_{net} = 10
> $$
> So,
> $$
> E^\circ_{net} = \frac{n_{red}E^\circ_{red} + n_{ox}E^\circ_{ox}}{n_{net}}
> = \frac{2(1.51)+5(0.49)}{10} = 0.547V$$

which is approx. 4 times lower than given answer.

So, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Both n_ox and n_red are 10. You have to multiple respective half-reactions by 2 resp. 5 to match them.

Comment: There is a fundamental misunderstanding as to what 'n' in -nFE represents. It represents the number of electrons and not a multiplier to your reaction stoichiometry. Understand that $E^o$ is an intrinsic value and deltaG is extrinsic the 'n' accounts for the number of electrons.

Comment: @zynox I converted your answer into a comment. It looks correct but it was being downvoted, presumably because it requires some elaboration (I don't know the actual reason).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the standard reduction potential is an intensive property, but the standard reaction Gibbs energy is an extensive property scaling proportionally with formal multiplication of reaction coefficients. It still matches the potential, as the electron count changes with the scaled standard reaction Gibbs energy the same way.

To evaluate standard Gibbs reaction energy and the cell potential, both half reactions have to be scaled to the same electron counts, leading to the standard cell potential(voltage) being simple subtraction of standard reduction potentials of both half-reactions and standard reaction Gibbs energy being subtraction of scaled standard  half-reaction Gibbs energies.

In the above particular case for Gibbs energy evaluation:

\begin{align}
\Delta_\text{r} G^{\circ} &= 5 \cdot \Delta G^{\circ}_\text{ox} + 2 \cdot \Delta G^{\circ}_\mathrm{red}=\\
&=5 \cdot (-2 \cdot F\cdot E^{\circ}_\text{ox}) + 2 \cdot(- 5 \cdot F \cdot E^{\circ}_\text{red})=\\
&= -10 \cdot F\cdot E^{\circ}_\text{ox} - 10 \cdot F \cdot E^{\circ}_\text{red}\\
\\
E^{\circ}_\text{cell} &= - \frac{\Delta_\text{r} G^{\circ}}{10F} =  E^{\circ}_\text{ox} +E^{\circ}_\text{red}=\\
&= -(\pu{-0.49 V}) + \pu{1.51 V} =\\
&= \pu{+2 V}
\end{align}